# Create a mail domain for a site on the Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My client’s site is hosted on Google’s cloud platform. I need to configure an email domain on this site. For example, I have a test.com site, how can I create an admin@test.com email domain for it? How to set up email domain on the Google cloud platform?

I found only paid Google services for this purpose, but this option is not suitable.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you do not use a service like Office 365 or G Suite, you will be blocked by almost every service. Your emails will either be refused or automatically put in the junk folder. Your email server IP address will most likely be considered hostile until you have been sending email for a while (months). This is called email reputation.  If you want to send legitimate email, you will need to pay for it today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option is to use Google Compute Engine to do this. If you want to stay in the free tier, follow the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/).

Although I would recommend just using GSuite basic, it will cost money but will be far far less hassle for you and your client. They will pay more in the long run paying someone intermittently to keep the solution running than just paying for GSuite in the first place.